# System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in the XML document (1, 1).'

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

This error is showing up in my code, there is a second one that is as follows:

> XmlException: The existing data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

I checked this second one saying there is a error with the file when there isn't any since I have 5 files inside my XMLFiles directory.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImportSession));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            sw.Write(stream);
            sw.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;


        }

        Console.ReadKey();


        foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\XMLFiles", "*.xml"))
        {
            ProcessFile(filename, stream, serializer);
        }

        void ProcessFile(string Filename, MemoryStream stream, XmlSerializer serializer)
        {
            bool temErro = false;
            Console.WriteLine("A processar xml: " + Filename);
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(Filename);

            ImportSession session = (ImportSession)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            foreach (Batch batch in session.Batches)
            {
                foreach (Document doc in batch.Documents)
                {
                    foreach (Page page in doc.Pages)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(batch.Processed.ToString()))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(page.HasError.ToString()))
                            {
                                string Import = page.ImportFileName;
                                Console.WriteLine("Página com erro:" + Import);
                                temErro = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (temErro)
                Console.WriteLine("Ficheiro com erro: " + Filename);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Ficheiro processado: " + Filename);

            Console.WriteLine(Filename);
        }

    }

public class ImportSession
{
    public Batch[] Batches { get; set; }
}
public class Batch
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string BatchClassName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool Processed { get; set; }



    public Document[] Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FormTypeName { get; set; }
    public IndexField[] IndexFields { get; set; }
    public Page[] Pages { get; set; }
}

public class IndexField
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ImportFileName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool HasError => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage);
}
```

This app right now is only trying to read all the files and point out some parts that need to show up in the console and it was doing it but I was adviced on here to change into this object oriented and memory stream.

Comment: The error is in the xml. Post it.

Comment: @Fildor there are 5 xml files and this app will be used to read at least 100 a hour they all come from another app that doesn´t give out errors and the errors it gives in the files are those messages that i need to show in the app

Comment: You don't need the StreamWriter and MemoryStream. I had those in a Fiddle, to load the literal XML, because we cannot load from file in dotnetfiddle.

Comment: ill post one here but i can´t post every file it wont be good right? you sure its gonna be a error with the xml file?

Comment: "saying there is a error with the file when there isen´t any" I'm going to trust the library here; why not *log the xml* when it fails. You might be surprised to find that is not, in fact, what you think it is

Comment: @MarcGravell I say there isen´t any cause the app was working the other way i made it and the files are the same how do i log it?

Comment: question: `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))` and `sw.Write(stream);` - what do you think that means? I don't think it means *anything*. What are the contents *meant* to be, and why?

Comment: it was the way i was told to do it so i used it

Comment: _"it was the way i was told to do it so i used it"_ - not exactly, though. I said to ignore that part. (See comment above)

Comment: but isen´t that part for the insert into the db? @Fildor

Comment: No, it isn't. That was just to have a stream containing the xml, so the example _from then on_ made sense.

Comment: @Fildor then what do i do cause im really not understanding anything anymore

Comment: It would be enough to keep the XmlSerializer line and the foreach-loop in the main method.

Comment: @Fildor if u can check the edited post is that what you meant?

Comment: Not exactly. See my answer, I hope it clears up your confusion.

Comment: see my answer to your answe @Fildor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```cs
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            sw.Write(stream);
            sw.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
```

is basically meaningless. Whatever the contents of `stream` are meant to be: it isn't this. Ask yourself:

> What is `stream` meant to contain?

At the moment it contains... itself, sort of, but not really?

If you intend the stream to be the file contents: just use `File.OpenRead`

Comment: that part will be used to insert into a database trough a sp

Comment: Hi Marc, sorry: I guess this is my fault. I showed OP some examples in a fiddle, where we obviouslay cannot load from file. So I created a stream from literal. And this seems to be a residue.

Comment: @TiagoSilva how? that's the stream that you *read from*, in `serializer.Deserialize(stream)`; so: where is it meant to get content from?

Comment: @Fildor if its anyone´s fault its mine im the one who cant do anything, sorry to both of u

Comment: @TiagoSilva for context: right now, the stream contain the string: `"System.IO.MemoryStream"` - nothing more, nothing less; that *probably* isn't what you intended

Comment: no it wasen´t i just didnt understood what fildor was teaching me i f it up think u guys can help me out make this work?

Comment: @TiagoSilva again: what is it *meant* to contain? If you just want to read the file: `File.OpenRead`. If you want to also store it in a DB: `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);` and then you can do `new MemoryStream(bytes)` *and* just pass the same `bytes` down to a DB/etc

Comment: @MarcGravell i need to do both so ill try it out, since Fildor is trying to help me out im gonna finish using is method and if it doens´t work ill try out yours im sorry for this but i never used this type of coding and im really under water here so to say

Answer (score 1):

I think this is based on a misunderstanding from answers to previous questions on the topic.

This should make it *work*. **BUT** keep in mind, that it *is in no way **production-ready***.

```
public static void Main()
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImportSession));
    foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\XMLFiles", "*.xml"))
        {
            ProcessFile(filename, serializer);
        }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void ProcessFile(string Filename, XmlSerializer serializer)
{
    bool temErro = false;
    Console.WriteLine("A processar xml: " + Filename);

    using (var file = File.OpenRead(Filename)) { 
        var session = (ImportSession)serializer.Deserialize(file);

// from here on the rest of your code ...
```

To minimize the code that keeps the file opened:

```cs
    ImportSession session;
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(Filename)) 
    { 
            session = (ImportSession)serializer.Deserialize(file);
    } 
    // file will be closed by disposal of FileStream using this notation

    // rest of code
```

---

### Addendum

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(batch.Processed.ToString()))
{   // Will ALWAYS be entered!
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(page.HasError.ToString()))
    {   // Will ALWAYS be entered!
        string Import = page.ImportFileName;
        Console.WriteLine("Página com erro:" + Import);
        temErro = true;
    }
}
```

Let's look at it:
`!string.IsNullOrEmpty(page.HasError.ToString())` is always true. Why?

`page.HasError` is of type `bool`. So, `page.HasError.ToString()` *"Converts the value of this instance to its equivalent string representation (**either "True" or "False"**)."*

So, it will never be `null` or `empty`. So, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will always be false, and `!string.IsNullOrEmpty` therefore always be true.

If you want to check the boolean value, you simply do `if( page.HasError )` => "Page has an error"

Comment: it gives out errors on stream and xmlSerializer in the processFile plus the foreach loop inside main cant call processfile

Comment: important: the file still needs closing, ideally with `using`

Comment: what file? can you be more specific please?

Comment: @TiagoSilva fine: `using (var file = File.OpenRead(FileName)) { var session = (ImportSession)serializer.Deserialize(file); // ... }`

Comment: does the rest of the code stay inside  the using var file?

Comment: If you use this notation, then yes. Otherwise `session` goes out of scope.

Comment: I added an alternative with minimal code to keep the file open. I.e. File will be closed as soon as possible.

Comment: @Fildor i tried it out ye the session now stays but it keeps giving errors in the using() var file on the FileName saying it doens´t exist in the current context the same thing happens  with stream and serializer on the processfile(here)

Comment: Typo. `FileName` should have been `Filename`. Of course they need to match ...

Comment: I tried it out it works thank you now i just need to figure out why its returning everything with the error message when there is only one file with one line with error @Fildor

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(batch.Processed.ToString()))` and `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(page.HasError.ToString()))` - Processed and HasError are boolean. That means neither `Processed.ToString()` nor `HasError.ToString()` is ever going to be null or empty. @TiagoSilva If you want to check their values you can simply do `if( page.HasError )` to check if `page.HasError` is true.

Comment: ohh ok then how can i switch that so that it lets the processed be 1 or 0 and the hasError be the same eith 1 or 0 since if its one it does have a error message and 0 it doens´t @Fildor

Comment: If you want to check for `processed == 1` then you do `if( batch.Processed )` and if you want to check for `processed == 0` you do `if( !batch.Processed )`.

Comment: and what if i want to check if it as error?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You already do? If you fix the bool check, it should work as expected.

Comment: ahh ok so just take out the bool and instead of saying page.haserror i put page.errormessage can it be like that?

Comment: That's exactly what `HasError` is doing for your convenience: `public bool HasError => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage);`

Comment: Actually, you can combine both if lines: `if( !batch.Processed && page.HasError ){ /*do what you do when page has an error*/ } `

Comment: Niceeee its working haha now time to try to insert into the db @Fildor

Comment: Good luck with that! Have fun coding :D

Comment: sure will haha @Fildor